# Date function in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Access for a database and I need to write SQL queries to display information. I can't figure out how to display what I need.

In English, I need a query to display the Description with the Expiration Date when the Expiration Date is less than thirty days from the current date.

My knowledge of SQL is limited. If anyone could point me to specific resources it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT Description, [Expiration Date]
FROM Hardware
WHERE [Expiration Date] = "(GET DATE()";
```

Comment: from shortly looking into this i would guess it is simply `Date()` http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210604/en-us

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions `NOW()` and `DATE()` to get the current date.

To add days to a date, use the [DATEADD](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx) function.

```
WHERE DATEADD(d, 30, [Expiration Date]) >= DATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Description], [Expiration Date]
FROM Hardware
WHERE DateDiff('d', [Expiration Date], Date()) < 30;
```

Note `Description` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#D).  I enclosed it in square brackets to avoid confusing the db engine.

Also that `DateDiff` expression only counts the number of day changes.  That means `#2013-9-23 23:00#` to `#2013-9-24 01:00#` would be counted as 1 day.  If that's not what you want, you can do date arithmetic directly on the Date/Time values.

```
SELECT [Description], [Expiration Date]
FROM Hardware
WHERE (Date() - [Expiration Date]) < 30;
```

If `Hardware` is a huge table with an index on `[Expiration Date]`, you can get better performance with a query which supports indexed retrieval rather than examining every row of the table.

```
SELECT [Description], [Expiration Date]
FROM Hardware
WHERE [Expiration Date] > (Date() - 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
SELECT Description, [Expiration Date]
FROM Hardware
WHERE DATEDIFF([Expiration Date], NOW()) < 30;
```

or this :

```
 SELECT Description, [Expiration Date]
FROM Hardware
WHERE [Expiration Date] < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

should work.